# Never odd or even

Tags: riddle

- I can be long or short and most people can appreciate me.
- But not everyone can easily create me.
- If I see you mirrored, you are me.
- But if I see myself mirrored, I am not.

What am I?

Comment: How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you

> A palindrome

I can be long or short and most people can appreciate me.

> Palindromes can be short ("Madam, I'm Adam") or longer ("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!") and people generally appreciate the cleverness, not least because...

not everyone can easily create me.

If I see you mirrored, you are me.

> If you look at me and see me mirrored, I must be the same as myself mirrored

But if I see myself mirrored, I am not.

> If I can look at myself and tell that I am mirrored, then I must not be the same as my mirror image.

Finally,

> The title of the puzzle is a palindrome

Comment: Ha, nice, I completely forgot about the last part (of your answer)! I think this might be it.

Comment: Good work! Correct. But see my answer for some explanation on how I meant it. (I couldn't place comments with spoilers here.)

Comment: Knowing songs from Weird Al Yankovic, I knew answer before I read the question.

Comment: I don't understand the mirrored part at all...

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer -

> shadow

long or short

> shadow can be long or short

But not everyone can easily create me

> Transparent objects cannot create shadow.

Mirror

> shadow in mirror does not create actual image of us.

Comment: Ooh. That's a nice one. But no, that's not it.

Answer (score 4):

See the answer of @aPaulT , which is correct. But a part of his explanation isn't how I intended it:

If I see you mirrored, you are me.

> Since I am a palindrome, If I can look at you mirrored and still see you, then you are a palindrome (thus me).

But if I see myself mirrored, I am not.

> Because if you mirror `palindrome`, you get `emordnilap`. So I, palindrome, am not a palindrome, thus I am not myself.

Comment: My first guess was ton: There's a short ton and a long ton and when mirrored it reads "not". I culdn't make that guess fit with the rest of the clues, of course.

Comment: Are you by any chance familiar with Weird Al Yankovic's "Bob"?

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Reflection

I can be long or short and most people can appreciate me.

> Depending on the height of the person, or convex/concave mirror. Most people can appreciate their own reflection

But not everyone can easily create me.

> Not everyone can easily create a reflection, due to surface maybe?

If I see you mirrored, you are me.

> If the reflection sees you mirrored, then you are the same as the reflection

But if I see myself mirrored, I am not.

> If the reflection sees itself mirrored, then is not the same as the reflection (following from the line above, "you are me" to "I am not [me]" - ie. from the point of view of the reflection, it's own reflection is not the same as itself - it's mirrored)

Comment: Also not what I was looking for. Plus I don't follow what you say in your last line.

Comment: @nl-x I just edited to try to explain a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Sounds vague, but are you:

> A biography

I can be long or short and most people can appreciate me.

> Biographies can be long or short

But not everyone can easily create me.

> It is not easy to write one.

If I see you mirrored, you are me.

> I am a biography if I am about you (for example).

But if I see myself mirrored, I am not.

> But if I am about the writer, then I am not a biography. I would be an autobiography then.

Comment: No price for you either :)